# Problemas con setSupportActionBar(toolbar) en android studio

Tags: java, android, toolbar

Soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación móvil y he tenido un problema al momento de estar creando una toolbar en el código java, este no me reconoce el objeto creado con el nombre toolbar en setSupportActionBar(toolbar), aquí les dejo el código:

```
package com.example.jayrosalazar.platzigram.view;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;

import com.example.jayrosalazar.platzigram.R;

public class CreatAccountActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_creat_account);
        showToolbar(getResources().getString(R.string.toobar_tittle_createaccount),false);
    }

    //Método para visualizar y crear un Toolbar
    public void showToolbar(String tittle, boolean upButton){
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar) //Declaramos un objeto tipo Toolbar y lo instanciamos
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(tittle);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(upButton);
    }

}
```

Aquí les dejo el layout en xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: La aplicación se detiene? Marca algún error de compilación? Puedes agregar mas detalles

Answer (score 1):

Esto se debe a que en las librerías que importas estas llamando a la librería:

```
import android.widget.Toolbar;
```

Y deberías estar llamando a la librería que declaraste en el XML de tu layout que es:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

Reemplaza el primer import por el segundo y debería funcionar, siempre y cuando no hayas realizado cambios en el XML que deberia quedar asi:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que estás usando [`android.widget.Toolbar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) en el código y deberías usar [`android.support.v7.Toolbar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html), ya que así lo definiste en el xml :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
```

Además estás usando el método `setSupportActionBar()` que toma como parámetro un objeto `Toolbar` de la librería de soporte de Android.

Answer (score 0):

Con la nueva actualización de google a androidx no te va a funcionar ese código  tienes que migrar de la siguiente forma de esto:

```
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.os.Bundle

a esto;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
```

Igualmente debes cambiar tu toolbar para que quede de la siguiente manera si:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Me comentas, yo también me demore como 4 horas en este problema

Comment: Mucha gracias... Alexander Cruz.. tu respuesta fue mi solución!!!!!