# Error Toolbar Android, setSupportActionBar,

Tags: android

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No consigo corregir el error del setsupporActionBar He intentado cambiar la herencia de appCompat  a Activity y sigue igual. Muchas Gracias por su tiempo

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.Tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Tal cual como lo tienes, edita la pregunta, copia y pega el código, en vez de poner una imagen. Sera mucho mas fácil ayudarte. Saludos.

Comment: esto fue preguntado anteriormente, te sugiero revisar primero en el sitio, saludos https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/127419/problemas-con-setsupportactionbartoolbar-en-android-studio/173782#173782

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en la declaración del `setSupporActionBar`.

Tu estás declarando un `toolbar` que viene de `android.widget.Toolbar` y ese tipo de `toolbar` no puede ser asignado al `setSupporActionBar`.

Para solucionar el error necesitas quitar la importación de `android.widget.Toolbar` e importar `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` que es el que necesitas en este caso.

Como se puede ver en la imagen es el error del que te avisa android studio.

Comment: He intentado cambiar la herencia y aun asi sigue dando errores

Comment: Editada la respuesta.